# Wordpress issue importing .xml (Load Balanced website)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, import, export, load-balancing

I am moving posts from an old blog to my 'newer' blog and have used the standard Wordpress Import & Export tools for the exporting from the old blog then importing into the new blog.

When I import the xml file into my new blog and assign the authors I get the following error:

```
Sorry, there has been an error. The file does not exist, please try again.
```

Not sure if this makes a difference but our website is currently hosted on Rackspace with a load balancer with 2 indentical instances of the website (but only one single database). I'm not sure if the load balancer will be the cause for this - however I did try the very same process on another almost identical website that **DOESN'T** have any load balancing on it and that worked fine without a hitch.

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem?

Comment: Check this [troubleshooting guide](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list).

Comment: It was related to the load balancing.. but somehow even though it gave me an error it HAD imported the data.. rather strange works well so its all good now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to the load balancing.. but somehow even though it gave me an error it HAD imported the data.. rather strange works well so its all good now :)

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering the same issue on an nginx load-balanced server setup, but unfortunately it hadn't imported the data no matter how many times I tried. I was unable to check the logs, but as far as I could tell: Wordpress likely polls the URL of the uploaded file, and the load balancer redirects those polls to alternate servers (i.e. ones where the uploaded file doesn't exist), which in turn causes the error.

The most straightforward solution was to temporarily disable the load-balancing so that the site was only being served from a single server. Then the import process completed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who encounters this issue with the WordPress importer on a load balanced environment, if your load balancing environment has an option for session "stickiness", turning that on will solve this problem.