# Wordpress import error (default import tools)

Tags: wordpress

Error message:

> Sorry, there has been an error. The file does not exist, please try
>   again.

I am importing XML file. What could it be?

Is not:

- Server problem
- The problem of XML generation
- Plugins impact

Comment: This error comes because of load balancing, visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717399/wordpress-issue-importing-xml-load-balanced-website)

Comment: @HritikPandey This problem repeated on local version

Comment: @HritikPandey Or If this is a really described problem, how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried this plugin?? https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Comment: @HritikPandey I want to import only some post types.

Comment: You can do this using this plugin..